# Mongodb failed with error Failed to optimize expression?

Tags: mongodb

I have a query like below,
It always return error:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Failed to optimize expression :: caused by :: Failed to optimize expression :: caused by :: Failed to optimize expression :: caused by :: Incorrect number of non-equivalent expressions",
    "code" : 3401204,
    "codeName" : "Location3401204",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1631084334, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1631084334, 1)
}
```

If I delete some condition in $and.$or it can works. please review my query and how to fix it error. I have a nested $and and $or because have some conditions more if needed. In case it's unnecessary. So I want to keep this query format

Thanks in advance

Query:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
   "p":ObjectId("609100a56ed9f8001351aee3"),
   "$and":[
      {
         "$or":[
            {
               "a":"1"
            },
            {
               "a":"2"
            },
            {
               "a":"3"
            },
            {
               "a":"4"
            },
            {
               "a":"5"
            },
            {
               "a":"6"
            },
            {
               "a":"7"
            },
            {
               "a":"8"
            },
            {
               "a":"9"
            },
            {
               "a":"10"
            },
            {
               "a":"11"
            },
            {
               "a":"12"
            },
            {
               "a":"13"
            },
            {
               "a":"14"
            },
            {
               "a":"15"
            },
            {
               "a":"16"
            },
            {
               "a":"17"
            },
            {
               "a":"18"
            },
            {
               "a":"19"
            },
            {
               "a":"20"
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^(1|2).*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^3.*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^4.*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^5.*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^6.*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^7.*/i"
               }
            },
            {
               "a":{
                  "$regex":"/^8.*/i"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "$or":[
      {
         "$or":[
            {
               "_id":ObjectId("5ca45ca25f6c44001004609a")
            },
            {
               "_id":ObjectId("5ca45ca25f6c44001004609a")
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}).sort({ name: 1 }).collation({ locale: 'en_US'})
```

Comment: Instead of many conditions in the `$or` for the same field, you can try using the `$in` operator - the code will come cleaner and readable.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. It also resolve the issue.

Comment: @prasad_ This error happen when I upgrade mongo version to v5.0, old version is v4.0. Do you know what the difference between v5 and v4. I'm facing with many same error

Comment: We are facing the same problem, I have captured a ticket here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-66379

Comment: nice @dnickless